# Trouble debugging protractor in IntelliJ

Tags: protractor

I had my setup working just fine a month or so ago in my project for debugging my protractor scripts in IntelliJ.

However, since the project upgraded to Angular 2 release and Protractor 4.0.9, I have been unable get the debugging to work.

The error I'm getting is:

`Error message: No selenium server jar found at the specified location (./node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar). Check that the version number is up to date.`

So, realizing that maybe I forgot to run `webdriver-manager update`. And while it appeared like selenium got updated, it did not get updated in my project's node_modules folder (referenced above).

Thinking there may be something wrong, which sometimes happens, I nuked the node_modules folder, ran npm install, ran webdriver-manager update, and... I still have the same problem.

My Run/Debug Configurations item for my test is as follows:

```
Node interpretor: /usr/local/bin/node 
Node parameters: --harmony
Working directory: [my project folder's root]
JavaScript file: node_modules/protractor/built/cli.js
Application parameters: test/e2e/myTestFile.conf.js
Environment variables: [none needed for this test]
Before launch: [blank]

Node is 6.5.0
Angular 2.0.0
protractor 4.0.9
And, fwiw, typescript 2.0.2
(Both the angular project and the protractor code are in typescript.)
```

Now, I am able to run my tests from the command line. But being able to step through code to find my errors, or be able to pause with access to my objects, which I can't do when I do a browser.pause().